# How to enforce standards and controls when using CDK Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, infrastructure-as-code

[CDK Pipelines](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/) is great, specially for cross-account deployments. It enables the developers to define and customize the CI/CD pipeline for their app to their heart's content.

But to remain SoC compliant, we need to make sure that necessary controls like below are validated/enforced

1. A manual approval stage **should be present** before the stage that does the cross-account deployment to production
2. Direct deployment to production bypassing dev/staging environment is not allowed
3. Test cases (Unit tests/Integration tests) and InfoSec tests should pass before deployment

I know that above things are straightforward to implement in CDK Pipelines but I am not quite sure about how to **ensure that every CDK Pipeline always conforms to these standards**.

I can think of below solutions

- Branch restrictions - Merge to master branch (which the CDK pipeline monitors) should be restricted and allowed only via pull requests
- Tests - Add unit tests or integration tests which validate that the generated cloud formation template has specific resources/properties
- Create a standard production stage with all necessary controls defined and wrap it in a library which developers need to use in their definition of the CDK Pipeline if the want to deploy to production

But how to enforce above controls in an automated fashion? Developers can choose to bypass above controls by simply not specifying them while defining the pipeline. And we do not want to rely on an Approver to check these things manually.

So in summary, the question is - When using CDK pipelines, how to give developers maximum customizability and freedom in designing their CI/CD solution while ensuring that SoC restrictions and mandatory controls are validated and enforced in an automated fashion?

Comment: You can not give them IAM permissions to deploy stacks, and only deploy the pipeline stack yourself (through whatever automated process) if it is using your library properly.

Comment: @kichik This will defeat the whole purpose of using CDK Pipelines - we want developers to be able to specify the pipeline as per their requirement - as long as it conforms to the set standards like deployment to prod account needs to be manually approved.

Comment: FTR - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk-rfcs/blob/master/text/0049-continuous-delivery.md documents the design of CDK pipelines

Comment: They can't still design the pipeline. They just can't deploy it directly without going through your tests first.

Answer (score 1):

Open Policy Agent might be helpful to check infra against custom policies in the pipeline.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/realize-policy-as-code-with-aws-cloud-development-kit-through-open-policy-agent/

Comment: Thanks Suhaib. This is very helpful. A validation stage which runs the checks using Open Policy Agent would be one of the potential ways to solve the stated problem. But unfortunately it would also suffer from the same issue - how to enforce that developers *always* add this stage when building their CI/CD Pipeline using CDK?

Comment: There are 2 ways:
Process 1: Allow only approved custom NPM/PIP modules created from AWS CDK.
In the pipeline for deploying these modules to Artifactory(private repository), you can enforce security requirements using OPA. This way you can make a whole library of  patterns overtime.

Process 2: Let developers use public AWS CDK modules and in the deploy stage run 'cdk synth > templete.yml' before running 'cdk deploy'. This allows you to run classic cloudformation linting tools like cfn-lint on this cloudformation created by aws cdk. You can configure your custom security rules in cfn-lint.

Comment: I agree that Process-1 is one of the options. But I am not sure if I fully understand Process-2. How would I ensure that developers do configure the deploy stage to run `cdk synth > template.yml` and then run cfn-lint?

Comment: You create pipeline in such a way that Deploy stage is managed by engineering and not developers. You can actually break deploy stage into 2 (security stage & deploy stage). Both these stages are maintained by engineering. 

Developers should only manage Build stage where npm/pip modules are pulled from Artifactory(private package repo) and build steps are executed. Build stage IAM role should not have deploy access.

If you're using Codepipeline with each stage being a separate Codebuild. Buildspec for Build stage is pushed by dev in code. Rest of the buildspec are managed by engineering.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Suhaib. Want to note here that we are a very small team without any clear distinction between Dev/Eng and I guess that's why we like CDK Pipelines - makes it easy to specify pipeline with minimal effort. It looks like the approach that you are suggesting would take away the simplicity of the pipeline, which we currently gain a lot from and are not sure if we want to let go.

I am currently thinking on the lines of having some [hook](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk-rfcs/issues/71#issuecomment-805527349). which does the validation and blocks the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot, concluded that implementing these checks via a [custom AWS Config rule](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwidhrqNhO7vAhUTX30KHWbJCKYQFjABegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.aws.amazon.com%2Fconfig%2Flatest%2Fdeveloperguide%2Fevaluate-config_develop-rules_getting-started.html&usg=AOvVaw0-zWQMs7DJ6WlV6UOjKC5z) is the best approach.

Let's say we want  to ensure that

> A manual approval stage is always present in every pipeline that
> has a stage that deploys to prod.

We need to

1. Enable AWS Config and configure it to record all changes to Codepipeline
2. Create a custom AWS Config rule using AWS Lambda function (say **pipeline-compliance-checker**)

   1. The lambda function gets triggered on every config change of any codepipeline and receives the latest config of the pipeline in question
   2. It parses the latest pipeline config and checks whether the pipeline has a manual approval stage before the stage that deploys to prod. If yes, it deems the pipeline as COMPLIANT else NON_COMPLIANT
3. Create a AWS EventBridge rule to receive a notification to an SNS topic (say **pipeline-non-compliance**) when any pipeline is marked as NON_COMPLIANT - ([doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/config-resource-non-compliant/))
4. Create another AWS Lambda function (say **pipeline-compliance-enforcer**) that is subscribed to that SNS topic. It stops the non-compliant pipeline in question (if it is in STARTED state) and then disables the incoming transition to the stage that deploys to prod. We can also delete the pipeline here if required.

Have tested the above setup and it fulfils the requirements.

Also learnt later that AWS speaks about the same solution to this problem in this talk - [CI/CD Pipeline Security: Advanced Continuous Delivery Best Practices](https://youtu.be/BprhSs1eSWw?t=1940)